# Expanded DIV is not pushing other section div content down in Desktop resolution

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tablet, responsive

[image: Bootstrap grid requirement for Desktop expanded/collapsed div, tablet mode]

Hi,

We are trying to develop responsive divs with the following requirement -
* In Desktop mode - expanding right side div, should push all left divs one below another

We are able to achieve Tablet mode representation as per the requirement, but how to achieve floating of left divs in Desktop mode on expanding right div?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be done a number of ways, you may want to check out flexbox layouts. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need jquery to do that bro, just add action when button click and change class in box 2-5 from col-lg-6 to col-lg-12 and parent class box 1-5 from col-lg-8 to col-lg-4 then expanded right box from col-lg-4 to col-lg-8
i.e.

```
$('.button-expand').click(function(){
   $('.box-small').toggleClass('col-lg-6');
   $('.box-small').toggleClass('col-lg-12');
   $('.parent-box').toggleClass('col-lg-8');
   $('.parent-box').toggleClass('col-lg-4');
   $('.box-right').toggleClass('col-lg-8');
   $('.box-right').toggleClass('col-lg-4');
});
```